# How to get access token to pull Azure Monitor metrics for a specific subscription?

Tags: azure-active-directory, access-token, azure-resource-manager, azure-monitoring, microsoft-identity-platform

We need to generate an AAD access token which can be used for a client to query Azure Monitor metrics (though Fluent API) for a specific subscription. So the requirements are:
1. the token can only be used to query metrics for a specific subscription, but no others
2. only can query metrics from Azure Monitoring (through ARM I believe)

How can we:
1. obtain the access token?
2. For Azure Management Fluent SDK, how to use the token directly?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

> ***1. How to obtain access token to list Azure resource metrics***

a. create a service principal and assign Reader role for the sp. (I use Azure CLI to do that)

```
az login
az account set --subscription "<your subscription id>"
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "readMetric" --role Reader
```

[image]

b. get access token

```
POST /<your sp tenant>/oauth2/token HTTP/1.1
Host: login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
&client_id=<your sp appid>
&client_secret=<your sp password>
&resource=https://management.azure.com/
```

c. List metrics for one Azure resource

```
GET https://management.azure.com/{resource id}/providers/microsoft.insights/metrics?api-version=2018-01-01&metricnames=""
Authorization : Bearer <access_token>
```

[image]

> ***2. For Azure Management Fluent SDK, how to use the token directly?***

Regarding the issue, please refer to the following steps

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
        {
       /*
           Please install sdk Microsoft.IdentityModel.Clients.ActiveDirectory and Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent 

      */

            var tenantId = "<your sp tenant>";
            var clientId = "<your sp appId>";
            var clientSecret = "<your sp password>";
            var subscriptionId = "<your subscription id>";
            var context = new AuthenticationContext("https://login.microsoftonline.com/" + tenantId, false);
            var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId: clientId, clientSecret: clientSecret);
            var result = await context.AcquireTokenAsync("https://management.azure.com/", credential);

            var token = result.AccessToken;
            var tokenCredentials = new TokenCredentials(token);
            var azureCredentials = new AzureCredentials(
                tokenCredentials,
                tokenCredentials,
                tenantId,
                AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud);
            var client = RestClient
                .Configure()
                .WithEnvironment(AzureEnvironment.AzureGlobalCloud)
                .WithLogLevel(HttpLoggingDelegatingHandler.Level.Basic)
                .WithCredentials(azureCredentials)
                .Build();
            var azure = Microsoft.Azure.Management.Fluent.Azure
                          .Authenticate(client, tenantId)
                          .WithSubscription(subscriptionId);
            var resourceId = "/subscriptions/e5b0fcfa-e859-43f3-8d84-5e5fe29f4c68/resourceGroups/jimtest/providers/Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/testvm";
            foreach (var metricDefinition in await azure.MetricDefinitions.ListByResourceAsync(resourceId))
            {
                var metricCollection = await metricDefinition.DefineQuery()
                                .StartingFrom(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5))
                                .EndsBefore(DateTime.UtcNow)
                                .ExecuteAsync();
                Console.WriteLine("Metrics for '" + resourceId + "':");
                Console.WriteLine("Namespacse: " + metricCollection.Namespace);
                Console.WriteLine("Query time: " + metricCollection.Timespan);
                Console.WriteLine("Time Grain: " + metricCollection.Interval);
                Console.WriteLine("Cost: " + metricCollection.Cost);
                foreach (var metric in metricCollection.Metrics)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("\tMetric: " + metric.Name.LocalizedValue);
                    Console.WriteLine("\tType: " + metric.Type);
                    Console.WriteLine("\tUnit: " + metric.Unit);
                    Console.WriteLine("\tTime Series: ");
                    foreach (var timeElement in metric.Timeseries)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("\t\tMetadata: ");
                        foreach (var metadata in timeElement.Metadatavalues)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t" + metadata.Name.LocalizedValue + ": " + metadata.Value);
                        }
                        Console.WriteLine("\t\tData: ");
                        foreach (var data in timeElement.Data)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("\t\t\t" + data.TimeStamp
                                    + " : (Min) " + data.Minimum
                                    + " : (Max) " + data.Maximum
                                    + " : (Avg) " + data.Average
                                    + " : (Total) " + data.Total
                                    + " : (Count) " + data.Count);
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
  }
```

[image]

For more details, please refer to the [document](https://github.com/Azure/azure-libraries-for-net)

Comment: Thanks. Please see my separate reply since too long for the comment. So basically our service has an SP which has access to multiple subscriptions. The client however cannot access the SP; it needs to ask our service for an access token which is scoped down to its subscription only; then it uses the token to query (this can be done easily with REST API, but not sure about Fluent SDK).

Comment: @YuWang I think the issue has been resolved. If you have other concerns, I suggest you create a new issue.

Comment: No it's not. I know how to create custom role, how to create SP and how to get token. But the question is how to scope the obtained token if the SP has permission of multiple roles against multiple subscriptions. We do not want to use multiple SP.

Answer (score 0):

Let me clarify a bit more on my problems.

The service has an SP which already has permission to query ARM for a number of subscriptions. Now there are a bunch of metrics clients which are doing metrics query work for each individual subscription. Due to security reason, these clients cannot access the service SP; in order to query metrics, the proposal is that for each individual client, it can first request a token for its subscription from the service, and use the token to query metrics.

Now whenever the service receives the token request from a client, it should ask AAD for an access token, which is scoped to only the corresponding subscription (since the SP has access to multiple subscriptions by default), and distribute back to the client. We don't want the client to use the obtained token to either query metrics of another subscription or to read resource other than metrics.

Comment: If you  do not want the access token to read other resources, you can create a custom role to implement it. For more details, please refer to https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/roles-permissions-security#monitoring-permissions-and-custom-rbac-roles

Comment: The SP will need to have multiple roles (monitor reader and contributor for example) on multiple subscriptions. I need to know how to get a token with this SP which only: 1. has monitor reader role (but no contributor permission). 2. only against one subscription.

Comment: As far as I knew, we have no way to implement it. When we use the sp to get the access token, the access token will contain the sp's all permissions?